# ICS FTP - Upload a folder containing multiple subfolders and files to a ftp server

Tags: delphi, ftp-client

I'm trying to upload a folder to a ftp server using Overbyte Ics Ftp component.
From what I understand there is no built in function to upload a folder containing files and sub-folders to a ftp so I have to create a recursion in order to upload them all into one call.
What is the correct approach to this problem?
I'm thinking about doing this:

- scan the local folder that I want to upload and separate folders from files
- for each folder name check if exists on the ftp. If not exists the create it
- after creating all folders to the ftp server check if local file exists on the ftp. If not exists start uploading the file to the created directory.

Is this the proper way to do it?
Is there an easier approach to this task?
Thank you!

Comment: To my knowledge the Ics Ftp client does not have a "magic" function to make it easier than you have already outlined. Try to have a look on `SendFile` and `MkdirAsyncButtonClick` in `.\Samples\Delphi\FtpDemos\OverbyteIcsFtpTst1.pas`. It will give inspiration on how to proceed. If you have further challenges in the process please post the code in an update to your question with your challenge.

Comment: Just note. You don't have to create folder tree first. Just create your recursion function and you synchronize just the current folder - check if exist and create folders and files, then go deeper and again. EDIT: I saw your other question. This time you will call LIST only once for each folder and you will check if each file or folder exist. You don't have to have a separate call for each folder.

Comment: Have you looked at TMagFTP component which is built on top of ICS?  http://www.magsys.co.uk/delphi/magxfer.asp